# Using MPMediaItems with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is it possible to pick media items using MPMediaPickerController and then load them into an AVAudioPlayer object?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If `MPMusicPlayerController` doesn't meet your needs, you can [copy the audio to your local bundle](http://blog.tapsquare.com/post/803301658/ipod-library-access) so you can use `AVAudioPlayer`.

**EDIT**

You basically have three options for playing audio from the user's iPod library: `MPMediaPlayer`, `AVPlayer` and `AVAudioPlayer`.

Here are examples for `MPMediaPlayer` and `AVPlayer`:

```
- (void) mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker
   didPickMediaItems: (MPMediaItemCollection *) collection {


    MPMediaItem *item = [[collection items] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSURL *url = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];

    // Play the item using MPMusicPlayer

    MPMusicPlayerController* appMusicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];

    [appMusicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection:collection];
    [appMusicPlayer play];


    // Play the item using AVPlayer

    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:url];
    AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    [player play];  

}
```

If you need to use `AVAudioPlayer` for some reason, or you need access to the audio file's actual audio data, you have to first copy the audio file to your app's directory and then work with it there. The `AVAsset` + `AVPlayer` stuff is the closest analogy to `ALAsset` if you're used to working with photos and videos.

Comment: So audio assets in the form of AVAssets are used like ALAssets?

Comment: I am trying to play music at host side, connected joins hear same music which is playing on host side. From host side i try to send media item to join side through connected sessions but media item not sending. Kindly tell me how i send media item from host to join (client) side? By the way i successfully send media title and media artwork. Thanks.

Comment: Link probably should be updated — either to [archival version](https://web.archive.org/web/20130603064710/http://blog.tapsquare.com/post/803301658/ipod-library-access) or straight to the [bitbucket repo](https://bitbucket.org/artgillespie/tslibraryimport) it refers to.

Comment: By using this:

 MPMediaItem *item = [[collection items] objectAtIndex:0];
 NSURL *url = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];

It shows me, URL is null.

Answer (score 16):

Just wanted to say that it appears that in iOS 6 and 7, AVAudioPlayer can play file URLs directly from the iPod without having to copy the audio data into your app directory as Art suggested.

```
- (void) mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker didPickMediaItems: (MPMediaItemCollection *) collection {


    MPMediaItem *item = [[collection items] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSURL *url = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];

    // Play the item using AVPlayer
    self.avAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    [self.avAudioPlayer play];
}
```

Comment: it couse -43 NSOSStatusErrorDomain when using media query

Comment: Can someone verify that AVAudioPlayer can really play a song from the iPod library? It's become more important now that setVolume is deprecated on the MPMusicPlayerController.

Comment: i use AVAudioPlayer to play iPod songs in both iOS 6 and 7. It works.

Comment: Some songs don't work - in particular I've noticed some songs that were purchased >6 years ago don't work for me - I assume the DRM does not allow them to be played outside of the Music app...

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to add (and I can't comment on SO yet) that it seems like in iOS 8, and perhaps before, songs that are stored on iCloud do not have a value for the property `assetURL` and return `null` for `[npItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL]`.

Here is a sample output:

```
MPMediaItem *npItem = self.musicPlayerController.nowPlayingItem;
NSLog(@"Song Title: %@\n assetURL: %@\n Cloud Item: %d", npItem.title, [npItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL], npItem.cloudItem)


// Log Output
Song Title: Time We Had
assetURL: (null)
Cloud Item: 1

Song Title: The Quiet
assetURL: ipod-library://item/item.m4a?id=1529654720874100371
Cloud Item: 0
```

Comment: Is there a way to distinguish between the "old" DRM protected songs and songs on the iCloud?

Answer (score -3):

I think you'll find that the `[NSBundle mainBundle]` is READ-ONLY. It's not possible to write files into the APP, therefore `AVAudioPlayer` will not work for iPod-Library `MPMediaItems`!