# is it possible to play back from a specific point or time in a MPMediaItem?

Tags: ios, mpmediaitem, mpmediaplayercontroller

Is it possible to play change the playback position from a MPMediaItem? I would like to be able to move between different points in a audio file (say a song) held on the devices iTunes library. Which framework should I be using?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it by myself. But here's a [link to documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/General_Media_Item_Property_Keys) that i hope could help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via the AVPlayer. See [Using MPMediaItems with AVAudioPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222464/using-mpmediaitems-with-avaudioplayer) for details. Works via the MPMediaItem's URL.