# Play items from MPMediaItemCollection in AVPlayer [Swift]

Tags: swift, avplayer, mpmediaitemcollection

Here is the thing, I have a MPMediaItemCollection with user choosen items(from the library). I used the mediaPicker to do that. Now, I need to get the URL from these items so I can play them on a AVPlayer. [This is the best I can find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222464/using-mpmediaitems-with-avaudioplayer), but when I "translate" to swift it gets messed up. If someone can help me I would appreciate a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is your swift code:

```
func mediaPicker(mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController!, didPickMediaItems mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection!) {

    for thisItem in mediaItemCollection.items as! [MPMediaItem] {
        let itemUrl = thisItem.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL) as? NSURL
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        // Play the item using MPMusicPlayer
        var appMusicPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer()
        appMusicPlayer.play()

        // Play the item using AVPlayer
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: itemUrl)
        let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        player.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much, it worked perfectly, but I have a doubt. When more than one music is chosen it only plays the last one. Do you know how to change it?

Comment: You just need to get the first item  mediaItemCollection.items.first as! MPMediaItem